# RxJava2 How to do some operations when zipping two data source completed

Tags: java, rx-java2

I am processing two mono wav files and I want to save them as stereo file.
Each mono is streamed and subscribed as follows.
The mono data can have different length.
I used zip operator to process pairs.
The problem is that I have to call:

```
fileWriter.stopRecord();
```

when processing both data is completed.
So I wanted to do it in zip onCompleted method but it doesn't work because
after one mono is processed (onCompleted called) it calls zip onCompleted but the other mono is still processing.
So how can I make sure that zip onCompleted is called after both mono are processed ? It doesn't matter that one value of pair may be null.

```
        Observable<HermesMessages.AudioChunk> speakerAudioObservable = this.channel.getSpeakerAudio();

        speakerAudioObservable.subscribe(
                sample -> {
                    log.trace("Processing speaker !!!" );
                },
                error -> {
                    log.error("Error during writing to file", error);
                }, () -> {
                    log.trace("Completed writing speaker audio to file.");
                });

        Observable<HermesMessages.AudioChunk> dronAudioObservable = channel.getDronAudio();
        dronAudioObservable.subscribe(
                sample -> {
                    log.trace("Processing dron !!!" );

                },
                error -> {
                    log.error("Error during writing to file", error);
                },
                () -> {
                    log.trace("Completed writing dron audio to file.");
                });

        Observable.zip(speakerAudioObservable, dronAudioObservable, Pair::create)
                .subscribe(
                        pair -> {
                            fileWriter.streamSecData(pair.first().getContent());
                            fileWriter.workerJob();

                            fileWriter.streamData(pair.second().getContent());
                            fileWriter.workerJob();
                        },
                        error -> {
                            log.error("zip Error during writing to file", error);
                            fileWriter.stopRecord();

                        }, () -> {
                            log.trace("zip Completed writing speaker audio to file.");
                            fileWriter.stopRecord();
                        });
```

Comment: You don't have to subscribe to every `Observable` but just to the zipped version `Observable.zip`

Comment: Your are right, but still it doesn't work since data can have different length

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with zip because the stream is finished when one of the observables zipped finishes emitting items. (source: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html).

But you can use another operator called CombineLatest. It combines an item emitted by the an observable with the last item emitted by the other observable. The downside would be that you have to check whether a item has already been "proccesed"(created already a pair from this item). So you have to change the `Pair::create` method. Also no need to subscribe to each observable individually.

Source: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html

Answer (score 0):

I have done a simple solution testing with some Integers
Hope this solution will help you
2 streams of integers with not the same size

```
 public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    Observable<Integer> integerObservable1 = Observable.just(1, 2, 3,4);
    Observable<Integer> integerObservable2 = Observable.just(1, 2);

    runObservable(integerObservable1, integerObservable2)
    .map(o -> {
        System.out.println(o);
        return o;
    }).subscribe();
}

private Observable<Object> runObservable(Observable<Integer> integerObservable1, Observable<Integer> integerObservable2) {
    return Observable.merge(
            Observable.zip(integerObservable1, integerObservable2, (BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Object>) (integer, integer2) -> integer + " " + integer2),

            Single.zip(integerObservable1.toList(), integerObservable2.toList(), (integers, integers2) -> Math.min(integers.size(), integers2.size()))
                    .flatMapObservable(integer -> Observable.merge(integerObservable1.skip(integer), integerObservable2.skip(integer)))
                    .map(integer -> integer + " " + "static value")
    );
}
```

output of code :

1 1

2 2

3 static value

4 static value

as stream 1 have 2 elements and stream 2 have 4 elements you i left it static as null is no supported in rxjava but you can chose if static value could be null or last value